# Printing firebase errors on component from vuex store, (getting errors in order to be translated later with i18n)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuex

thank you in advance for reading me. So I'm new to vuex and after configuring my store, now I want to get my firebase errors displayed on my components, I wanted to catch them via specific code error, so I can translated to 3 different languages later, so far I had no luck. So my store declarations looks something like this, I put as example the login action where I'm trying to get the errors into a state. The error part is more like what I want to achieve, is not clear if I need to pass it as payload .

```
//My sample vuex action for  login 

const loginAction = (context, payload) => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            context.commit('logIn', userCredential.user.uid);
            console.log('userCredential', userCredential)
            router.push('/');
            context.dispatch('retrieveDbValues');
            return true;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'auth/invalid-email':
                    error.message = 'The email is invalid'
                    break
                case 'auth/user-not-found':
                    error.message = 'No account with that email was found'
                    break
                case 'auth/wrong-password':
                    error.message = 'The password is incorrect'
                    break
                default:
                    error.message = 'Email or password was incorrect'
                    break
            }
        });
}

//My current mutation for this  error

setError(state, payload) {
    state.error = payload;
},


//My state with the error value 

export default{
    state:{
            error: null
    }
}

//My sample with getterns for error

getters: {
    error(state) {
        return state.error;
    }
}
```

Now in my login component, I have something like this inside my form declaration at the top

```
<form id="signup-form" @submit.prevent="checkForm">
  <p v-if="error"> {{ error }} </p>
...
</form>
```

And in my computed methods from my login component I have something like

```
  computed:{
    error(){
      return this.$store.getters.error;
    }
  }
```

In that catch error above, in the first block of code, it is more like what I want to achieve. I also tried the simple version just printing the error without the code(see example below), but also did not work.

```
.catch(error => {
            context.commit('setError', error.message);
        
        });
```

When testing, meaning I just submit the email and I intentionally write a wrong password, I don't get the error printed, just the error in the console, "server respond with status 400" which i think is correct, because couldn't connect but not error displayed in my component. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Solved so it seems was needed a small twick on the vuex action, because I was not entering to the catch for some reason, so I asked if (credentials) on the then:

```
const loginAction = (context, payload) => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            if (userCredential) {
                context.commit('logIn', userCredential.user.uid);
                router.push('/');
                context.dispatch('retrieveDbValues');
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            context.commit('setError', firebaseErrors[error.code] || error.message);
            console.log(error.code);
            
        });
}
```

And in the catch error, I'm passing a constant that have the error codes from firebase, so I have them setup to be translated in the vue store. And all of this is declared in my same vuex store.

```
const firebaseErrors = {
    'auth/user-not-found': 'No user corresponding to this email or have a typo',// No user corresponding to this email or have a typo
    'auth/invalid-email':'The email is not valid',
    'auth/wrong-password':'The password is incorrect',
};
```

And for me this is working, hope it helps some else

Comment: I like how you set this up, but I was trying to figure out how to keep error handling out of Vuex, but I can't get the accurate firebase auth error to bubble up to the component. I only get a higher level error of "res isn't defined" rather than the more helpful "user not found" -- any ideas?